# C++ STL's String eqivalent for Binary Data

Tags: c++, string, stl, binary

I am writing a C++ application and I was wondering what the C++ conventional way of storing a byte array in memory.

Is there something like a string, except specifically made for binary data.

Right now I am using a *unsigned char**  array to store the data, but something more STL/C++ like would be better.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441203/proper-way-to-store-binary-data-with-c-stl

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'd use `std::vector<unsigned char>`. Most operations you need can be done using the STL with iterator ranges. Also, remember that if you really need the raw data `&v[0]` is guaranteed to give a pointer to the underlying array.

Comment: No need to rely on `&v[0]` when `v.data()` is clearer.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement Indeed, however back in 2009 `data()` wasn't defined on `std::vector`.

Answer (score 24):

You can use `std::string` also for binary data. The length of the data in `std::string` is stored explicitly and not determined by null-termination, so null-bytes don't have special meaning in a `std::string`.

`std::string` is often more convenient than `std::vector<char>` because it provides many methods that are useful to work with binary data but not provided by `vector`. To parse/create binary data it is useful to have things like `substr()`, overloads for `+` and `std::stringstream` at your disposal. On vectors the algorithms from `<algorithm>` can be used to achieve the same effects, but it's more clumsy than the string methods. If you just act on "sequences of characters", `std::string` gives you the methods you usually want, even if these sequences happen to contain "binary" data.

Comment: or std::vector<unsigned char>

Comment: I would also use std::vector<unsigned char>.

Comment: std::vector<unsigned char> has the advantage that one can get its contents as a /writable/ char pointer (by &vec[0]). On the other hand, you don't get the copy-on-write optimization common in std::string implementations.

Comment: @bdonlan: A writable buffer from &obj[0] is also true for std::string implicitly through the other requirements.  In fact, 0x makes this explicit.

Answer (score 21):

You should use `std::vector<unsigned char>` or `std::vector<uint8_t>` (if you have a modern `stdint.h` header).  There's nothing wrong with using `unsigned char[]` or `uint8_t[]` if you are working with fixed size buffers.  Where `std::vector` really shines is when you need to grow or append to your buffers frequently.  STL iterators have the same semantics as pointers, so STL algorithms will work equally well with `std::vector` and plain old arrays.

And as CAdaker pointed out, the expression `&v[0]` is guaranteed to give you the underlying pointer to the vector's buffer (and it's guaranteed to be one contiguous block of memory).  This guarantee was added in an addendum to the C++ standard.

Personally, I'd avoid using `std::string` to manipulate arbitrary byte buffers, since I think it's potentially confusing, but it's not an unheard of practice.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions but the closest one (I feel) is the  `std::vector<std::byte>>` because it expresses the intent directly in code.

From : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte

> std::byte is a distinct type that implements the concept of byte as
>   specified in the C++ language definition.
>
> Like char and unsigned char, it can be used to access raw memory
>   occupied by other objects (object representation), but unlike those
>   types, it is not a character type and is not an arithmetic type. A
>   byte is only a collection of bits, and the only operators defined for
>   it are the bitwise ones.

Answer (score 0):

how about `std::basic_string<uint8_t>` ?