# Apache Thrift : difference between byte and binary types

Tags: c++, binary, byte, sequence, thrift

I would like to send 1024 bytes of data using Thrift. It must be exactly 1024 bytes because it is a comparative benchmark with other frameworks.

Thrift has two types to represent bytes : 'byte' and 'binary', but I don't know how to use these types.
'binary' type is mapped to std::string which is quite strange  (I don't understand why and how to use it).
'byte' type is mapped to a 8 bits integer which seems more logical to me.

To represent 1024 bytes of data, I use : `list<byte> byteSequence` with a size of 1024.

But a compile warning advises me to use `binary` instead of `list<byte>`, but why ? and how ?

I think I will get much better performance with 'binary' because it is strangely slow with a 1024 sequence of bytes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably depends on the language you will be compiling your thrift files to, but `binary` tells thrift directly that you indeed want to transmit a sequence of raw, unencoded bytes.

It may not change things much at the transport layer in terms of size, but you may run into surprises when you instantiate/de-serialise the objects in your chosen language. In Java, for example, a `binary` field will be represented with a `byte[]` whereas `list[byte]` will give you a `List[Byte]`, which is far less efficient to represent the same thing.

Java might be the only reason for `binary`, as according to the [thrift doc](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/types):

> binary: a sequence of unencoded bytes
>
> N.B.: This is currently a specialized form of the string type above, **added to provide better interoperability with Java**. The current plan-of-record is to elevate this to a base type at some point.

Comment: I am compiling with C++. If I understand well, there would not be performance difference between using list[byte] or binary in C++ ? I would like to try myself, but I don't understand how to use the binary type in C++, because it is mapped to std::string. How can I represent 1024 bytes of data with a std::string ?

Comment: I'm no C++ expert, but from googling a bit it seems that std::string is fine for holding and manipulating binary data. E.g: http://stackoverflow.com/a/837528/1997056

Comment: Ok so I try that : string sequence ; for (int j=0; j<1024 ; j++) sequence+=(char)0; And I get better performance. I hope this method is good. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That comment may need some revision. `binary` is a base type for a long time now.

Answer (score 4):

> But a compile warning advises me to use binary instead of list, but why ? and how ?
>
> 'byte' type is mapped to a 8 bits integer which seems more logical to me.

And that's exactly why the warning is there. It seems logical but it is the worst choice. Furthermore, `byte` in Thrift is in fact an `i8` - a *signed* type.

> 'binary' type is mapped to std::string which is quite strange (I don't understand why).

Don't worry. That's an historical thing. The `binary`type was added later and implemented similar to `string` in some ways to reduce compatibility friction with older versions. That's just an impl detail.

> but I don't know how to use these types.

Like any other type:

```
 struct wtf {
   1 : binary foo
   2 : string bar
   3 : byte baz     // i8 is replacing byte to indicate the signedness
   4 : list<byte>   // not recommended, but nevertheless works 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. When I say "I don't know how to use it", I mean I don't know how to represent exactly 1024 bytes with a string. I've done it this way : string sequence ; for (int j=0; j<1024 ; j++) sequence+=(char)0; but I don't really know if it is a good way.

Comment: `std::string()` has some useful CTORs, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/166646/499466). Something like putting e.g. 1024 times the letter`A` should do the trick.