# binary buffers for communication, c++

Tags: c++, winapi, stl, memory-management, malloc

If I need a binary buffer object,
like that used for TCP/UDP communication,
what would I base it on, in c++ ?

- `vector<unsigned char>` ?
- `std::string` ? -- std::string can hold 0-bytes, contrary to popular belief, so it can be used to hold binary data
- `new char[]` ?
- `malloc()` ?

Did anybody see std::vector used for binary buffers ?
I did not see. Why ? Performance ?

And I did see malloc() often used for binary buffers.
In C++. Can anybody confirm ? Explain ?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect the answers going to depend on what you want to use the buffer for and how you want to use it.

Comment: Boost Asio uses/recommends vector of char for storing binary data. so I think it should not give any performance problems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A binary buffer can be just seen as a piece of memory that you reserve for storing some unstructured information.
In this sense, using new `char[]` and `malloc` are perfectly equivalent, IMO, in that they give you a piece of memory and a pointer to it.

Using `std::vector` is a different matter; aside from the cost, which I don't think is relevant since you will use

```
&vect[0]
```

to access the underlying buffer like you would do with `malloc`, it has its advantages, like buffer extensibility and more access safety than a straight pointer; you might read the [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441203/proper-way-to-store-binary-data-with-c-stl). I have used them in a project myself.

`std::string`s have in principle the problem of the C++ (98, 03) standard not guaranteeing the contiguousness of the underlying buffer, but this does not seem to be an issue with compiler implementations. C++0x seems to have standardized buffer contiguousness (but I have not searched for that specifically). So you could also use them, but read before [Herb Sutter's comment here](http://herbsutter.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/) (it is not in the main article body, but in the third comment posted at the end of it).

Anyway, between `std::string` and `std::vector`, I would choose `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `new` and `malloc` is that new also calls the constructor (if there is any) for the entity it allocates memory to. But since char is a basic type using `new` or `malloc` makes no difference as char does not have a constructor. The same can be said about `delete` and `free`.

I would personally use a char* buffer (a char is 1 byte in memory):

```
char* buf = new char[100];
```

Also, remember when freeing the allocated buffer, to use a construct like:

```
delete[] buf;
```

to delete the array [otherwise you will have memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703691/how-does-delete-know-its-an-array-c).

I would *not* personally use a `std::string` or a `std::vector` because:

- a simple array of char seems faster to me
- more "universal" (there are several implementations of std but an array of byte will always be the same)
- and it might be easier to understand and debug

HTH,
JP

Comment: To nitpick, you *can* value-construct integral types and arrays thereof (which default to 0), so `new char[100]()` should give you a zeroed-out array. Support for this may vary at the moment, though. Also note that `new` is an *expression*, while `malloc()` is a *function*.

Comment: Your point about it being faster is debatable. The speed difference is negligible at most, and you get better resource scoping and type safety. I'd argue that the cognitive burden of handling arrays is not worth the speed "gains" (if any).

Comment: @Pablo: I would imagine that since std::string has attached logic it must be slower

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on how your program work. Is a client or a server? Will send/receive fixed length request? Do you need to modify the data later? Do you want to manipulate as a string or not?

I'd use std::string since it's most flexible on this regards. But as you can see, it's not optimal.