# Serializing vector of objects to std::string for use with MPI

Tags: c++, serialization, mpi

I am trying to communicate a `std::vector<MyClass>` with varying size via MPI. `MyClass` contains members that are vectors that may be uninitialized or vary in size. To do that, I wrote a `serialize()` und `deserialize()` function that reads and writes such a `std::vector<MyClass>` to a `std::string`, which I then communicate via MPI.

```
class MyClass {
    ...
    int some_int_member;
    std::vector<float> some_vector_member;
}

std::vector<MyClass> deserialize(const std::string &in) {
    std::istringstream iss(in);

    size_t total_size;
    iss.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&total_size), sizeof(total_size));

    std::vector<MyClass> out_vec;
    out_vec.resize(total_size);

    for(MyClass &d: out_vec) {
        size_t v_size;
        iss.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&d.some_int_member), sizeof(d.some_int_member));
        iss.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&v_size), sizeof(v_size));
        d.some_vector_member.resize(v_size);
        iss.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&d.some_vector_member[0]), v_size * sizeof(float));
    }

    return out_vec;
}


std::string serialize(std::vector<MyClass> &data) {
    std::ostringstream os;

    size_t total_size = data.size();
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&total_size), sizeof(total_size));

    for(MyClass &d: data) {
        size_t v_size = d.some_vector_member.size();
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&some_int_member), sizeof(some_int_member));
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&v_size), sizeof(v_size));
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&d.some_vector_member[0]), v_size * sizeof(float));
    }
    return os.str();
}
```

My implementation works in principle, but sometimes (not always!) MPI processes crash at positions I think are related to the serialization. The payload sent can be as big as hundrets of MB. I suspect that using `std::string` as a container is not a good choice. Are there some limitations using `std::string` as a container for `char[]` with huge binary data that I may be running into here?

(Note, that I don't want to use `boost::mpi` along with its serialization routines, neither do I want to pull in a huge library such as `cereal` into my project)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want from an answer. Is this about the crashes? Then we need an [mcve] and a description of your present debugging efforts. Or is this about how to do serialization properly? Or is this how to send compound C++ objects with MPI (serialization is only one answer to that)? If this is really about "*implement the sending of serialized data via MPI*", then at the very least we'd need to see your MPI code. Many of those questions are also heavy on opinion ("*better way*") please focus the question on specific goals and criteria.

Comment: Hi Zulan, I'm sorry that the question is not very precise. I'll try to rephrase it. I am using the above routines in a large numerical simulation which _sometimes_ crashes, even if there was no problem for many MPI requests. The stack trace is not very helpful (it contains `bad_alloc`, so I guess its some memory thing), and I am not easily able to create a minimal working example. I suspected some limitations of `std::string` to be the issue, therefore my question.

Comment: You could try to encapsulate your serialize method in a `try {...} catch(std::bad_alloc&) { ... }` block. Moreover, you could use a memory profiler to analyze memory leaks.

Comment: Although strings might work, MPI provides its own portable ways to serialise (pack) data using `MPI_Pack` and `MPI_Unpack`. Also, you might want to look into the implementation of serialisation in Boost.MPI.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, using `std::string` for binary data is fine although some people might prefer `std::vector<char>` - or `std::vector<std::byte>` in C++17 ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/441203/620382), note C++11 strings guarantee contiguous data). There are two significant efficiency issues in your code:

1. You always have three copies of the whole data. The original objects, the serialized `string` and the intermediate `[io]stringstream`.
2. You cannot pre-allocate (reserve) data in `ostringstream`, which may lead to over-allocation and frequent reallocation.

Hence, you waste a significant amount of memory, which might contribute to `bad_alloc`. That said, it may be perfectly fine and you just have a memory leak somewhere. It's impossible to tell if this is a practical issue for you without knowing the cause of the `bad_alloc` and a performance analysis of your application.