# Why adding a number to an associative container's iterator is not possible?

Tags: c++, containers, stl

I have an std::set and I wanted to iterate trough the element pairs in the set so I wrote 2 for loops like this:

```
for(std::set<T>::iterator i=mySet.begin();i!=mySet.end();++i)
{
    for(std::set<T>::iterator j=i+1;j!=mySet.end();++j)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The compiler told me that I can't add numbers to iterator. However I can increment and decrement them. A workaround I find that I can skip the first iteration:

```
for(std::set<T>::iterator i=mySet.begin();i!=mySet.end();++i)
{
    std::set<T>::iterator j=i;
    for(++j;j!=mySet.end();++j)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Why I can't just add a number why I have to increment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do this only with random access iterator, so the reasons are the same as for not having an indexoperator on containers when it would be slow. See also [Why isn't there an operator[] for a std::list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112724/why-isnt-there-an-operator-for-a-stdlist)

Comment: This is a conscious design decision from the STL guys. Rather than hiding the cost, they prefer you to use the more verbose form `std::advance(j, n);` so that it LOOKS slower. This is a hint (if you often need to increment by more than 1) that you should change your data structure :)

Answer (score 2):

As usual, Boost has a solution:

```
for(std::set<T>::iterator i=mySet.begin();i!=mySet.end();++i)
{
    for(std::set<T>::iterator j=boost::next(i);j!=mySet.end();++j)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Of course you could also consider

```
for(std::set<T>::iterator i=mySet.begin();i!=mySet.end();/* NOTHING */)
{
    std::for_each(++i, mySet.end(), /* do something*/ );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because set only supports bidirectional iterator, that only allows increments and decrements.

Set is usually a tree structure therefore these are the only operations that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/) at the definition of iterators. The method which you are looking for is defined only for iterators of containers which allows random access which set doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was already answered, but note that you can shorten your code like this:

```
for(std::set<T>::iterator i=mySet.begin();i!=mySet.end();++i)
{
    for(std::set<T>::iterator j=i;++j!=mySet.end();)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```