# What's the difference between std::advance and std::next?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

Is there more beyond advance takes negative numbers?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

[`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)

- modifies its argument
- returns nothing
- works on input iterators or better (or bi-directional iterators if a negative distance is given)

[`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)

- leaves its argument unmodified
- returns a copy of the argument, advanced by the specified amount
- works on forward iterators or better (or bi-directional iterators if a negative distance is given))

Comment: I don't suppose you happen to know why they made it UB to use `next` on an input iterator that's not a forward iterator, even though the defined effect of `next` is guaranteed to work on an input iterator?

Comment: @HowardHinnant: gah, thanks. So basically if you're working with an InputIterator then you should just use `++` (or `advance`, to protect yourself from the devastating convenience of one-liners involving `next`), or write your own `my_next` that quite possibly is identical to your implementation's `std::next`, maybe with a traits assertion removed. It occurs to me that on the same argument, InputIterator shouldn't require `operator++(int)`. Way too late to fix that now, I suppose.

Comment: If I had a time machine I would take away InputIterator's copy constructor and make it move-only.  I think that would make them much safer and easier to reason about.

Comment: The extra constraint on `std::next` was backed out by http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2353

Answer (score 21):

Perhaps the biggest practical difference is that [`std::next()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) is only available from C++11.

[`std::next()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) will advance by one by default, whereas [`std::advance()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) requires a distance.

And then there are the return values:

- [**`std::advance()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance): (none) (the iterator passed in is modified)
- [**`std::next()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next): The *n* th successor.

[`std::next()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) takes negative numbers just like `std::advance`, and in that case requires that the iterator must be bidirectional. [`std::prev()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) would be more readable when the intent is specifically to move backwards.

Comment: `next` doesn't only move forwards, it's like `advance` in that respect. Given the existence of `prev` it might be strange to write `next(it, -1)`, with a negated literal. But for iterators of the right categories it's fine for example to write `next(it, distance(it2, it3))` even if `it2 > it3`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Thanks for the edit and for preserving the emphasis on readability.

Comment: @Johnsyweb `std::next()` is available after C++11, not  only in C++11.

Comment: Thanks @John. The answer was correct when I wrote it nine years ago.

Answer (score 7):

**std::advance**

The function advance() increments the position of an iterator passed as the argument. Thus, the function lets the iterator step forward (or backward) more than one element:

```
#include <iterator>
void advance (InputIterator& pos, Dist n)
```

> - Lets the input iterator pos step n elements forward (**or backward**).
> - For bidirectional and random-access iterators, n may be negative to step backward.
> - Dist is a template type. Normally, it must be an integral type because operations such as <, ++, --, and comparisons with 0 are
>     called.
> - Note that advance() does not check whether it crosses the end() of a sequence (it can’t check because iterators in general do not know the
>     containers on which they operate). Thus, calling this function might
>     result in undefined behavior because calling operator ++ for the end
>     of a sequence is not defined.

**std::next**(and `std::prev` new in C++11)

```
#include <iterator>
ForwardIterator next (ForwardIterator pos)
ForwardIterator next (ForwardIterator pos, Dist n)
```

> - Yields the position the forward iterator pos would have if moved forward 1 or n positions.
> - For bidirectional and random-access iterators, n may be negative to yield previous  ositions.
> - Dist is type std::iterator_traits::difference_type.
> - Calls advance(pos,n) for an internal temporary object.
> - Note that next() does not check whether it crosses the end() of a sequence. Thus, it is up to the caller to ensure that the result is
>     valid.

cite from `The C++ Standard Library Second Edition`

Answer (score 4):

They're pretty much the same, except that `std::next` returns a copy and `std::advance` modifies its argument. Note that the standard requires `std::next` to behave like `std::advance`:

> #### 24.4.4 Iterator operations [iterator.operations]
>
> ```
> template <class InputIterator, class Distance>
> void advance(InputIterator& i [remark: reference], Distance n);
> ```
>
> 2. Requires: n shall be negative only for bidirectional and random access iterators
>   3. Effects: Increments (or decrements for negative n) iterator reference i by n.
>   [...]
>
> ```
> template <class ForwardIterator>
> ForwardIterator next(ForwardIterator x, [remark: copy]
>      typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::difference_type n = 1);
> ```
>
> 6. Effects: Equivalent to `advance(x, n); return x;`

Note that *both* actually support negative values if the iterator is an input iterator. Also note that `std::next` requires the iterator to meet the conditions of an ForwardIterator, while `std::advance` only needs an Input Iterator (if you don't use negative distances).