# Is there a way to iterate over at most N elements using range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

Is there a nice way to iterate over at most N elements in a container using a range-based `for` loop and/or algorithms from the standard library (that's the whole point, I know I can just use the "old" `for` loop with a condition).

Basically, I'm looking for something that corresponds to this Python code:

```
for i in arr[:N]:
    print(i)
```

Comment: @DavidHaim What exactly is confusing about "at most N elements"?

Comment: @DavidHaim It means that I would like to iterate over all elements in a container if its size is less or equal to N and over N elements otherwise.

Comment: @DavidHaim "at most N" -> `c.size() < N ? c.size() : N`

Comment: @DavidHaim: Perhaps you can further explain your confusion then, because the goal is clearly and unambiguously stated, and everybody else seems to get it!

Comment: @MarcoA.: Is it deliberate that below that code is the compiler output showing that it doesn't work? ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit damn no.. sorry.. started fiddling in the same link :/

Comment: With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/), [`for (auto&& e: input | ranges::view::take(N)) { /* stuff */ }`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8b2da6e1a924244).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20) you can add the range adaptor [`std::views::take`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/take_view) from the [Ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) to your [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). This way you can implement a similar solution to the one in [PiotrNycz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30782683/2675154), but without using Boost:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    const int N = 4;

    for (int i : v | std::views::take(N))
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        
    return 0;
}
```

The nice thing about this solution is that `N` may be larger than the size of the vector. This means, for the example above, it is safe to use `N = 13`; the complete vector will then be printed.

[Code on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ff0dahpZHItzVPLn)

Answer (score 39):

As I personally would use either [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30782359/1463922) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30782265/1463922) answer (+1 for both), just for increasing your knowledge - there are boost adapters you can use. For your case - the [sliced](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/sliced.html) seems the most appropriate:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/sliced.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> input={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    const int N = 4;
    using boost::adaptors::sliced;
    for (auto&& e: input | sliced(0, N))
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```

One important note: N is required by `sliced` to be not greater than `distance(range)` - so safer(and slower) version is as follows:

```
    for (auto&& e: input | sliced(0, std::min(N, input.size())))
```

So - once again - I would use simpler, old C/C++ approach (this you wanted to avoid in your question ;)

Comment: This is really neat! Does Boost also have some kind of array view that can give me only the elements that match a predicate or based on some index list?

Comment: @BaummitAugen - sure it has - look at `boost::adaptors::filtered`.  But for "index view" - probably not (I am not sure)...

Comment: Aside note: I am not really sure it is "so much" slower - good compiler with high optimization level should be able to generate similar binaries...

Comment: @BaummitAugen A few days later after your comment I encountered a real-world problem which requires to have such index view as you mentioned - and I managed to find such index view solution - so I posted on SO in Q/A format: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976131/is-this-possible-to-filter-rangecontainer-by-indexes-not-by-values-to-get-mi

Answer (score 15):

Here is the cheapest save solution that works for all forward iterators I could come up with:

```
auto begin = std::begin(range);
auto end = std::end(range);
if (std::distance(begin, end) > N)
    end = std::next(begin,N);
```

This might run through the range almost twice, but I see no other way to get the length of the range.

Comment: I would suggest `std::advance(begin, N)` instead of `std::next`. The former may take advantage of `RandomAccessInterator` if it is available, the latter will not.

Comment: @CoryKramer Why can't the latter take advantage of `RandomAccessInterator`? You could even easily implement `std::next` using `std::advance`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Looks like I lied, from the standard `§ 24.4.4.6` for `std::next()` *"Effects: Equivalent to advance(x, n); return x;"* I'm not sure that it is a **requirement** to take advantage of RandomAccessIterator, but it would be a shame if they didn't.

Comment: Still twice slower than alternatives. Not to mention poor readability.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I used `std::next` because I want the n-th successor of a given iterator, which is exactly what `std::next` is there for.

Comment: Actually, you know what? You're right. I take it all back, having read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15017115/560648). (Though PiotrNycz posted his answer I'm not completely convinced that this one is _fully_ what the OP was after!)

Comment: *This might run through the range almost twice*: a rather hairy issue for InputIterator (such as `std::cin`).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yep. That's why I wrote that my solutions works for forward iterators. For them it's fine.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the good old `break` to manually break a loop when needed. It works even with range based loop.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a{2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int cnt = 0;
    int n = 3;
    for (int x: a) {
       if (cnt++ >= n) break;
       std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: The question explicitly states he already knows how to do this with his own for loop. I realise he asks for ranged-for ideas as well, but your suggestion really doesn't add anything specific to ranged-for. He wants to adapt the standard algorithms, like `std::for_each`. That'll probably involve futzing with iterators.

Comment: In my opinion this solution is better than the .begin() and .end() stuff. Much easier to read, understand and code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I think in this case the OP should clarify his request in more details. Personally I treat the question as "what is the simplest way from the point of coding": just like range-based loop replaced the equivalent loop with iterators, the OP might want to make his code as clear as possible. Anyway, my answer matched the question in its current wording.

Comment: @Petr: I disagree, for the reasons given.

Comment: +1 "Range-based for and/or algorithms from the standard library" doesn't require std:: algorithms, and I like the simplicity here. Libraries are overkill, like a sledgehammer on a fly when you have a proper flyswatter anyway.

Answer (score 7):

C++ is great since you can code your own <s>hideous</s> solutions and hide them under an abstraction layer

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

//~-~-~-~-~-~-~- abstraction begins here ~-~-~-~-~-//
struct range {
 range(std::vector<int>& cnt) : m_container(cnt),
   m_end(cnt.end()) {}
 range& till(int N) {
     if (N >= m_container.size())
         m_end = m_container.end();
     else
        m_end = m_container.begin() + N;
     return *this;
 }
 std::vector<int>& m_container;
 std::vector<int>::iterator m_end;
 std::vector<int>::iterator begin() {
    return m_container.begin();
 }
 std::vector<int>::iterator end() {
    return m_end;
 }
};
//~-~-~-~-~-~-~- abstraction ends here ~-~-~-~-~-//

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a{11, 22, 33, 44, 55};
    int n = 4;

    range subRange(a);        
    for ( int i : subRange.till(n) ) {
       std::cout << i << std::endl; // prints 11, then 22, then 33, then 44
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a69470f30293cc7c)</kbd>

The above code obviously lacks some error checking and other adjustments, but I wanted to just express the idea clearly.

This works since [range-based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) produce code similar to the following

```
{
  auto && __range = range_expression ; 
  for (auto __begin = begin_expr,
       __end = end_expr; 
       __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
    range_declaration = *__begin; 
    loop_statement 
  } 
}
```

cfr. `begin_expr` and `end_expr`

Comment: Your code is illegal, the `range(a)` is a temporary, `till()` returns a reference to it and that reference is bound in the range-based for loop (`auto && __range = range_expression`). The intermediate temporaries in the expression are then deleted before the loop is executed - you end up with a dangling reference.

Comment: @DanielFrey you're right. Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

If your container doesn't have (or might not have) RandomAccessIterator, there is still a way to skin this cat:

```
int cnt = 0;
for(auto it=container.begin(); it != container.end() && cnt < N ; ++it,++cnt) {
  //
}
```

At least for me, it is very readable :-). And it has O(N) complexity regardless of container type.

Comment: -1: The question explicitly states he already knows how to do this with his own for loop. He wants to adapt the standard algorithms, like `std::for_each`. That'll probably involve futzing with iterators.

Answer (score 5):

This is an index iterator.  Mostly boilerplate, leaving it out, because I'm lazy.

```
template<class T>
struct indexT
 //: std::iterator< /* ... */ > // or do your own typedefs, or don't bother
{
  T t = {};
  indexT()=default;
  indexT(T tin):t(tin){}
  indexT& operator++(){ ++t; return *this; }
  indexT operator++(int){ auto tmp = *this; ++t; return tmp; }
  T operator*()const{return t;}
  bool operator==( indexT const& o )const{ return t==o.t; }
  bool operator!=( indexT const& o )const{ return t!=o.t; }
  // etc if you want full functionality.
  // The above is enough for a `for(:)` range-loop
};
```

it wraps a scalar type `T`, and on `*` returns a copy.  It also works on iterators, amusingly, which is useful here, as it lets us inherit effectively from a pointer:

```
template<class ItA, class ItB>
struct indexing_iterator:indexT<ItA> {
  ItB b;
  // TODO: add the typedefs required for an iterator here
  // that are going to be different than indexT<ItA>, like value_type
  // and reference etc.  (for simple use, not needed)
  indexing_iterator(ItA a, ItB bin):ItA(a), b(bin) {}
  indexT<ItA>& a() { return *this; }
  indexT<ItA> const& a() const { return *this; }
  decltype(auto) operator*() {
    return b[**a()];
  }
  decltype(auto) operator->() {
    return std::addressof(b[**a()]);
  }
};
```

The indexing iterator wraps two iterators, the second of which must be random-access.  It uses the first iterator to get an index, which it uses to look up a value from the second.

Next, we have is a range type.  A SFINAE-improved one can be found many places.  It makes iterating over a range of iterators in a `for(:)` loop easy:

```
template<class Iterator>
struct range {
  Iterator b = {};
  Iterator e = {};
  Iterator begin() { return b; }
  Iterator end() { return e; }
  range(Iterator s, Iterator f):b(s),e(f) {}
  range(Iterator s, size_t n):b(s), e(s+n) {}
  range()=default;
  decltype(auto) operator[](size_t N) { return b[N]; }
  decltype(auto) operator[] (size_t N) const { return b[N]; }\
  decltype(auto) front() { return *b; }
  decltype(auto) back() { return *std::prev(e); }
  bool empty() const { return begin()==end(); }
  size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
};
```

Here are helpers to make working with ranges of `indexT` easy:

```
template<class T>
using indexT_range = range<indexT<T>>;
using index = indexT<size_t>;
using index_range = range<index>;

template<class C>
size_t size(C&&c){return c.size();}
template<class T, std::size_t N>
size_t size(T(&)[N]){return N;}

index_range indexes( size_t start, size_t finish ) {
  return {index{start},index{finish}};
}
template<class C>
index_range indexes( C&& c ) {
  return make_indexes( 0, size(c) );
}
index_range intersect( index_range lhs, index_range rhs ) {
  if (lhs.b.t > rhs.e.t || rhs.b.t > lhs.b.t) return {};
  return {index{(std::max)(lhs.b.t, rhs.b.t)}, index{(std::min)(lhs.e.t, rhs.e.t)}};
}
```

ok, almost there.

`index_filter_it` takes a range of indexes and a random access iterator, and makes a range of indexed iterators into that random access iterator's data:

```
template<class R, class It>
auto index_filter_it( R&& r, It it ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  using ItA = decltype( begin(r) );
  using R = range<indexing_iterator<ItA, It>>;
  return R{{begin(r),it}, {end(r),it}};
}
```

`index_filter` takes an `index_range` and a random access container, intersects their indexes, then calls `index_filter_it`:

```
template<class C>
auto index_filter( index_range r, C& c ) {
  r = intersect( r, indexes(c) );
  using std::begin;
  return index_filter_it( r, begin(c) );
}
```

and now we have:

```
for (auto&& i : index_filter( indexes(0,6), arr )) {
}
```

and viola, we have a large musical instrument.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5941a9eceb0d9c8)

Fancier filters are possible.

```
size_t filter[] = {1,3,0,18,22,2,4};
using std::begin;
for (auto&& i : index_filter_it( filter, begin(arr) ) )
```

will visit 1, 3, 0, 18, 22, 2, 4 in `arr`.  It does not, however, bounds-check, unless `arr.begin()[]` bounds-checks.

There are probably errors in the above code, and you should probably just use `boost`.

If you implement `-` and `[]` on `indexT`, you can even daisy chain these ranges.

Answer (score 2):

This solution doesn't go past `end()`, has `O(N)` complexity for `std::list` (doesn't use `std::distance`) works with `std::for_each`, and only requires `ForwardIterator`:

```
std::vector<int> vect = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

auto stop_iter = vect.begin();
const size_t stop_count = 5;

if(stop_count <= vect.size())
{
    std::advance(stop_iter, n)
}
else
{
    stop_iter = vect.end();
}

std::for_each(vect.vegin(), stop_iter, [](auto val){ /* do stuff */ });
```

The only thing it doesn't do is work with `InputIterator` such as `std::istream_iterator` - you'll have to use external counter for that.

Comment: Same proposal than Marco A's, same issue with InputIterator.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Technically, that would make his solution same as mine, since mine was posted earlier. Anyway, his solution also provides a wrapper to use if range-based for loop, so they're not the same. Also, unless I interpret [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/sliced.html) wrong, [boost solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30782683/3811791) won't work with `InputIterator` either, since it requires `RandomAccessRange`.

Answer (score 2):

First we write an iterator which stops at a given index:

```
template<class I>
class at_most_iterator
  : public boost::iterator_facade<at_most_iterator<I>,
                  typename I::value_type,
                  boost::forward_traversal_tag>
{
private:
  I it_;
  int index_;
public:
  at_most_iterator(I it, int index) : it_(it), index_(index) {}
  at_most_iterator() {}
private:
  friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

  void increment()
  {
    ++it_;
    ++index_;
  }
  bool equal(at_most_iterator const& other) const
  {
    return this->index_ == other.index_ || this->it_ == other.it_;
  }
  typename std::iterator_traits<I>::reference dereference() const
  {
    return *it_;
  }
};
```

We can now write an algorithme for making a rage of this iterator from a given range:

```
template<class X>
boost::iterator_range<
  at_most_iterator<typename X::iterator>>
at_most(int i, X& xs)
{
  typedef typename X::iterator iterator;
  return std::make_pair(
            at_most_iterator<iterator>(xs.begin(), 0),
            at_most_iterator<iterator>(xs.end(), i)
        );
}
```

Usage:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::vector<int> xs = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  for(int x : at_most(5, xs))
    std::cout << x << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `equal` method is bothering me. I understand *why* you use a `||`, however I can think of issues with cyclic iterators (for example). I would propose to only refer to `index_` there, and not bothering with the iterators at all. Also (nit), don't use `int` for `index_`, prefer something like `size_t` as `int` could be as small as 16 bits for example.

Comment: I agree that size_t should be used.

Comment: If you do not compare the iterator, the code will break if the number of elements in the original range is lower than what we ask.

Comment: Indeed. But `|| this->it_ == other.it_` seems to be the wrong solution as it breaks a cycling iterator (and yes, the iterator pair concept in C++ makes things harder, a single object would be all too easy). I wonder if `sliced` in Boost adaptors handles cycling iterators.

Comment: Yes, having to use a pair-of-external-iterator makes this thing harfer than it should. I'm not so sure about what this code breaks w.r.t. a cycling iterator however.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ranges became part of C++ (in C++20), the way to achieve this is with a *view adapter*:

```
   container | std::views::take(N)
```

As the view is a range in its own right, we can use that in a `for` loop, or pass it to algorithms.

For example, the Python loop in the question is expressed as

```
   for (auto const& i: arr | std::views::take(N)) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
   }
```

Or, without the explicit loop:

```
   using value_type = typename decltype(arr)::value_type;
   auto print = std::ostream_iterator<value_type>{std::cout, '\n'};

   std::ranges::copy(arr | std::views::take(N), print);
```

Answer (score -1):

My favourite answer to this (now that we have C++20), is like this:

```cpp
for (const auto& foo : std::span{bar.begin(), num_iterations}) {
    // stuff
}
```

Using a span like this, we can iterate over any subsequence easily, using a range-based `for`:

```cpp
for (const auto& foo : std::span{bar.begin() + subsequence_start, num_iterations}) {
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: Not quite - that works over _exactly_ N elements, even if that's more than there are in the container.  And it most container types aren't convertible to `std::span` anyway.  The real answer is `for (const auto& foo: container | std::views::take(N))`

Comment: The point about indexing past the end of the range is fair in the sense that it's not equivalent to the python slice example, but if that's a concern you can easily add a std::min call. The python slice is also not really equivalent to "most container types", so that's not really a point. I'm going to have to strongly disagree that that's the "real" answer