# A way to filter range by indices, to get min_element from filtered indices only?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost, c++14

In comments to this question [is-there-a-way-to-iterate-over-at-most-n-elements-using-range-based-for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781811/is-there-a-way-to-iterate-over-at-most-n-elements-using-range-based-for-loop/) there was additional question - is this possible to have "index view" on a container, i.e. to have subrange with some indexes filtered out.

Additionally I encountered a problem to find minimum value from a range with some indexes filtered out.

I.e. is it possible to replace such code as below with std and/or boost algorithms, filters - to make it more readable and maintainable:

```
template <typename Range, typename IndexPredicate>
auto findMin(const Range& range, IndexPredicate ipred) 
     -> boost::optional<typename Range::value_type>
{
    bool found = false;
    typename Range::value_type minValue{};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < range.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (not ipred(i))
            continue;
        if (not found)
        {
            minValue = range[i];
            found = true;
        }
        else if (minValue > range[i])
        {
            minValue = range[i];
        }
    }
    if (found)
    {
        return minValue;
    }
    else
    {
        return boost::none;
    }
}
```

Just to be used like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<float> ff = {1.2,-1.2,2.3,-2.3};
    auto onlyEvenIndex = [](auto i){ return (i&1) == 0;};

    auto minValue = findMin(ff, onlyEvenIndex);
    std::cout << *minValue << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the recently Standard [**range-v3 proposal**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4382.pdf):

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<float> rng = {1.2,-1.2,2.3,-2.3};

    auto even_indices = 
        ranges::view::iota(0ul, rng.size()) | 
        ranges::view::filter([](auto i) { return !(i & 1); })
    ;
    auto min_ind = *ranges::min_element(
        even_indices, [&rng](auto L, auto R) { 
        return rng[L] < rng[R]; 
    });
    std::cout << rng[min_ind];
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/948b1f81f35e74d8). Note that the syntax is roughly similar to Boost.Range, but fully revamped to take advantage of C++14 (generalized lambdas, auto return type deduction etc.)

Comment: Is this proposal to C++17? Can I use it in gcc4.9?

Comment: Gcc 4.9 works in C++11 mode, use clang for c++14 mode (gcc 5.1 has some bugs that prevent c++14 mode). The proposal is on track for either c++17 or a TS, likely alongside c++17. See https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this is to think beyond the natural way of filtering ranges in C++. I mean - we need to filter the range of indexes, not the range of values. But from where we got the range of indexes? There is way to get the range of indexes - [boost::irange](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/boost/range/irange.hpp). So - see this:

```
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/filtered.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/min_element.hpp>
#include <functional>

template <typename Range, typename IndexPredicate>
auto findMin(const Range& range, IndexPredicate ipred) -> boost::optional<typename Range::value_type>
{
    using boost::adaptors::filtered;
    using boost::irange;

    auto filtered_indexes = irange(0u, range.size()) | filtered(std::function<bool(std::size_t)>{ipred});
```

One drawback of using boost ranges is that  [they have problems to use raw lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872558/using-boost-adaptors-with-c11-lambdas) - so that is why I need to use `std::function`.

Nest step is as easy as using `boost::min_element` - the only thing to remember is that you should compare values. not just indexes:

```
auto lessByValue = [&range] (auto lhs, auto rhs) 
{ 
      return range[lhs] < range[rhs]; 
};
```

And the final steps:

```
auto foundMin = boost::min_element(filtered_indexes, lessByValue);
if (foundMin != std::end(filtered_indexes))
    return range[*foundMin];
else 
    return boost::none;
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30789179/1774667) to the earlier question.  Optionally do the described tasks in that question augments.

Augment `indexT` to support a stride template argument `size_t stride=1`: Replace `++t;` with `std::advance(t,stride);`

Add `ItB base() const { return b+**a(); }` to `indexing_iterator` (this is for later).

Add `template<size_t stride> using index_stride_range=range<indexT<size_t, stride>>;`  This is an indexing range with a compile time stride.

Write `intersect` that works on two `index_stride_range`s.  The output is an `index_stride_range` of stride `gcd(lhs_stride, rhs_stride)`.  Working out where it starts is another bit of work, but only high-school math.  Note that an `index_range` is a type of `index_stride_range` with `stride=1`, so this upgrade will work with `index_range`s as well.

Upgrade `index_filter` to take a `index_stride_range` as the first argument.  The implementation is the same (other than relying on upgraded `intersect`).

Write `every_nth_index<N>(offset)`, which is an `index_stride_range` that goes from `offset` to `size_t(-(1+(abs(offset))%stride) - (size_t(-(1+(abs(offset)%stride)))%stride)` or some such (basically 0 to infinity in the simple case -- the extra math is to find the biggest number that is equal to offset+k*stride that fits in a `size_t`.

Now we get:

```
auto filtered = index_filter( every_nth_index<2>(), container );
auto it = (std::min)( filtered.begin(), filtered.end() );
```

and we have an iterator.  `it.base()` will return the iterator into the `container` that contains the element if `it!=filtered.end();` (not `it.base()!=container.end()`, which is different).

Comment: Do I have good feeling that this iterator approach could be also used to find minimum from every second while reading from a stream.. I mean it can be used not only for iterators being forward_iterator?

Comment: @PiotrNycz part of the previous answer relies on random access iterators (as it stores the `start` iterator and an index, and on dereference does `*(start+index)`).  But yes, variations can be written to support "skip every 2nd value" or whatever.  I was just noting that the answer I provided in the linked question was almost a solution to this problem as well.