# Why isn't std::next/prev templated by distance like std::advance?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

Out of curiosity, what's the rationale to use a template parameter for [`std::advance()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)'s distance type, but use the iterator's `difference_type` for the distance in [`std::next()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) and [`std::prev()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev)?

Why not use the same approach (either one)?

**Follow up:**

Presence of default `n = 1` does not seem to prevent `next` to be templated by `Distance` as was suggested in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69022834/2052436). This compiles:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <set>

template<typename InputIt,
    typename Distance = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type>
InputIt my_next(InputIt it, Distance n = 1)
{
    std::advance(it, n);
    return it;
}

int main()
{
    std::set<int> s;
    my_next(s.begin());
    my_next(s.begin(), 10ul);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not a duplicate, but closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017065/whats-the-difference-between-stdadvance-and-stdnext

Comment: I would say "history", `std::next` is from C++11, and has stronger type (and changing `std::advance` would certainly break ABI and/or other retro-compatibility concerns).

Answer (score 1):

It is needed to be able to compile both `std::next(it, n)` and `std::next(it)` with default 1:

```
template<typename InputIt , typename Distance>
InputIt 
next(InputIt it, Distance n = 1)
{
    std::advance(it, n);
    return it;
}

void foo(int *p)
{
    next(p, 1);         // ok
    next<int*, int>(p); // ok
    next(p);  // error: no matching function for call to 'next(int*&)'
}
```

There is a discussion of possible approaches to this overload resolution issue in gcc bugzilla: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40497

Comment: I don't follow. `std::next` doesn't even have a second template parameter.

Comment: @cigien I think this is demonstrating why exactly we cannot have a second template parameter (it prevents the use of a default parameter)

Comment: @Meowmere I'm not sure I understand. The second template parameter could have a default as well, say `typename Distance = int`, and then the `next(p)` call in this answer would compile just fine.

Comment: BTW, it only "answers" one possibility, `std::advance` might use `difference_type` (and possible implementation of en.cppreference.com uses it).