# c++: getting an object from a list by index doesnt work?

Tags: c++, list, class, oop, object

I'm new to c++, and recently I tried the following:

```
list<Someclass> listofobjects;
int Index;
cin >> Index;
Someclass anobject = listofobjects[Index];
```

As an output I get the following error:

```
../src/Kasse.h:98:71: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘((Someclass*)this)->Someclass::listofobjects[((Someclass*)this)->Someclass::Index]’
```

Does anyone know why? I just can't find a solution for this...
Thanks in advance

Comment: show the code declaring `listofobjects` an `Index`, now we can only guess what goes on

Comment: its in a class, but I've added the colums in the question, the list gets filled in the constructor of a class...

Comment: std::list has no operator []: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112724/why-isnt-there-an-operator-for-a-stdlist - you need eg vector if you want indexing (also that index should not be an `int` but a `size_t`)

Comment: QList has [] operator :) http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qlist.html

Comment: @otisonoza: Indeed, `QList` is closer to `std::deque` than `std::list`. `QLinkedList` is more like `std::list`. But this question is (presumably) about the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::list` is a doubly linked list - it allows you to iterate through it from the beginning or end, but doesn't allow random access to a particular index.

If you want that, perhaps you want a random-access container like `std::vector`, a dynamic array. You'll need to make sure it's large enough to contain the index you need:

```
if (Index >= listofobjects.size()) {
    listofobjects.resize(Index+1);
}
```

and you probably want a reference to the object in the list, not a copy, if you want to modify it:

```
Someclass & anobject = listofobjects[Index];
```

Alternatively, if you want a *sparse* array that only contains objects for the indices you actually use, you could use an associative map:

```
std::map<int, Someclass> objects;
Someclass & anobject = objects[Index];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, Im using std::vector now :)