# how print nth split of string with boost c++?

Tags: c++, boost, split

I need to get the 2nd split of a string, in the case below "two".

I tried running this code:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "one,two,three,four";
    std::list<std::string> results;

    boost::split(results, s, boost::is_any_of(","));

    std::cout << results[1] << "";
}
```

I get this error:

```
error: no match for 'operator[]'
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I know how split but I dont know how get the nth part  in this case get "two"

Comment: doesn't the `cout` line work? what does it print? by the way, prefer `std::vector` over `std::list`. `std::list` is a linked-list which is typically slower than `std::vector` and doesn't have a benefit here.

Comment: this part not work cout << results[1] << "";

Comment: IM confused , IM looking some examples but I dont found

Comment: please help me IM new in c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers given shows the reason for the error in that you are using a `std::list`, which in turn does not provide an `operator []`.  The easiest thing is to just use `std::vector`.

However, if you really wanted to use a `std::list`, the way you get to a certain position in the list is to advance to that position.  Thus there is a [std::advance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) function that does this, in addition to [std::next](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), which is merely a wrapper for `std::advance`.

So here is a solution using `std::list` and `std::advance`.

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "one,two,three,four";
    std::list<std::string> results;

    boost::split(results, s, boost::is_any_of(","));
    auto iter = results.begin();
    std::advance(iter, 1);
    std::cout << *iter << "";
}
```

[Live Example](https://www.ideone.com/nzG4lJ)

---

Now using `std::next`:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "one,two,three,four";
    std::list<std::string> results;

    boost::split(results, s, boost::is_any_of(","));
    auto iter = std::next(results.begin(), 1);
    std::cout << *iter << "";
}
```

[Live Example](https://www.ideone.com/SuWyMS)

Answer (score 0):

`cout << results[1] << "";`

This doesn't work because `results` is a `std::list`. [`std::list` does not provide the `[]` operator.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112724/why-isnt-there-an-operator-for-a-stdlist) In your usecase, you should use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: but how I could do this with list and boost exist any way?

Comment: why would you use `std::list` rather than `std::vector`?

Comment: Im new in c++ I know boost because use this ,  i dont know vector

Comment: It will work with `std::vector` too... you do not need `std::list` here.