A convenient way to access a range-v3 view element by index
I'm looking for a means to access, say, a filtered view element by index. Here is a snippet of code for context:
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto v_view = v | ranges::views::filter([](int value) { return value & 1; });

Now I want to access, say, the second element:
v_view.at(1) /* do some stuff */;

This won't compile with logs saying:
error: no matching member function for call to 'at'
   20 |     if (v_view.at(3) == 3) {
      |         ~~~~~~~^~
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.12.0/include/range/v3/view/interface.hpp:309:46: note: candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with True = true]
  309 |         constexpr range_reference_t<D<True>> at(range_difference_t<D<True>> n)
      |                                              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/0.12.0/include/range/v3/view/interface.hpp:308:31: note: because 'D<true>' (aka 'ranges::remove_if_view<ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int>>, ranges::logical_negate<(lambda at <source>:18:45)>>') does not satisfy 'random_access_range'
  308 |             requires True AND random_access_range<D<True>> AND sized_range<D<True>>)

It seems the function is expected to have constant time complexity and works only with a random access range, which is obviously not the case. Still, it is not clear to me why not to allow overloads for non-contiguous ranges with linear complexity. The only workaround I see is this:
*ranges::next(v_view.begin(), 1) /* do some stuff */;

Probably I'm missing something. Are there any options to work with views using indices, or am I forced to deal with its iterators explicitly?

liner is still worse than constant. I am not into ranges, but I suppose its the same as anywhere in the standard library where a method is not provided to avoid a drop in complexity by surprise

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1112724/5754656

@463035818_is_not_an_ai sounds more like an opinion-based statement. The reference may specify time complexity for some functions, but refuses to do so for others... I guess if a programmer cares about performance, it wouldn't be a problem for them to make sure an appropriate container is chosen and they wouldn't be surprised at the at method being linear for non-contiguous containers. Otherwise, why would they bother choosing non-contiguous containers if they do not know what they are?

opinion-based? No. Its not about my opinion. Its about an obervation of how the standard library handles methods for different kinds of containers and the common rationale. Its the same reason std::list has no operator[] for index based access.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai it is opinion based (but not SO-close-reason opinion-based): the committee's opinion is that inefficient things should be named differently to efficient things that compute equivalent values


Still, it is not clear to me why not to allow overloads for non-contiguous ranges with linear complexity.

One of the core guidelines is "don't waste time or space"..
The lack of at here matches the std containers. std::list is only bidirectional, as the best known way of accessing an arbitrary element is linear, it doesn't provide at or operator[]. std::forward_list is only forward, as the best known way of getting the previous element is linear1, it doesn't provide reverse iterators.
If you write a function template, taking an arbitrary container, and index into that, you can know the time complexity of specialisations of that function for every standard container, because indexing is either constant time, or not present. You don't have an algorithm that is silently worse in some cases.
If you don't care about complexity, you can write a free function at
template <std::ranges::forward_range Range>
std::ranges::range_reference_t<Range> at(Range & range, std::ranges::range_difference_t<Range> index) {
    return *std::ranges::next(range.begin(), index);
}

Alternately, if you are going to be doing multiple accesses by index, you could materialise the filtered view
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto v_filtered = v | std::ranges::views::filter([](int value) { return value & 1; }) | std::ranges::to<std::vector<int>>;


You count how far from begin you are, then advance begin one fewer times

